# My website is hacked and not showing right content in the google

Tags: google-product-search

My website was hacked before , but now i have changed my hosting service , i have moved my domain to new hosting and i have also changed name server also and it is working the pages there.
I have asked google for "Reconsideration" and google also done my website consideration but it is still showing wrong content there.
I am unable to understand from where it is showing that content in the google search.
Now in my new hosting i have added onlly one file name "index.php" still it is showing old content there.

My file data is in index.php.  My domain name is "jmbhglobal.com"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b5Ti.png)

and it is showing on google search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pzlF.png)

I have done all changes moved code to new hosting also done google reconsideration only one file is available there,

pls check it and help me.

Thanks

Comment: How much time has passed since you did "google reconsideration"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search results shows outdated site content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456610/google-search-results-shows-outdated-site-content)